# Read persistentVolumeClaims "Used" section from OCP with OpenShiftClient

Tags: openshift, fabric8, persistent-volume-claims, fabric8-maven-plugin, fabric8-kubernetes-client

I am using OpenShiftClient to read values from OCP.
So far I was able to read the Name, Status and Capacity values from persistentVolumeClaims Page without any issues.
But, when im reading all the values, im unable to find the values which appear in "Used" column in the client Object that im reading:
[OCP screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQCKH.png)

Any idea how can i do that?

looks like the object that OpenShiftClient returns doesn't provide it.

Alternatively, which oc cli command can I use to extract those values?

Comment: Can you see this used field in object json using `oc get pvc $name -ojson` ? looks like that field is computed.

Comment: No, i cannot see it using this command.
Neither with using "oc describe pvc $name".